# Calculating the average of a column in a CSV file using linq c#

Tags: c#, excel, linq, file, csv

I am really new to c# but I really want to start using linq to extract simple information from excel spreadsheets.

I feel quite embarrassed to ask this, but I can't seem to find a solution. Basically, all I want is find the average of the amount of donations within a CSV file.

[image: The Excel file layout]

This is following code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CSharpTest
{
    class Program
{
    public string Donor { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Charity { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        {

            var file = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Donations.csv".AsFile();

            File.ReadAllLines(file).Select(x => x.Split('\n')).Average(x => x.Count());


        }

    }
}
```

The thing is I know this is wrong as I only want the values in Amount. For something like this I am sure I should be using GroupBy(), however I can't seem to extract the public class Amount. I would be ever so grateful if someone could point me in the right direction please. Many thanks.

Comment: Time for [CSV Helper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)?

Comment: Do you want the average per person or the average across the whole file? You only need to group if you want the average per person or something. If you just want the average of the whole column no grouping needed. What you would need to do is split each line on `,` (rather than `\n` - you already have lines), take the third item (amount), parse it to a numeric type (eg decimal), and then apply your average operator. Several of these steps can be made easier by using a CSV parser as others have said.

Comment: I will defininitely take a look at CSV helper, many thanks - @DragandDrop

Comment: I was only after the average a whole, sorry for not being clearer. Oh of course splitting on , would make more sense. When you say take third item would it be something like: .Select(x => x[2] ..... ? It then gives a TryParseAs(). Many many thanks for the help @Chris

Comment: @DanielLee: Broadly yes getting the third item would be done as `x[2]` or similar. However do read the answers below with CSV Parsers. They are generally much better to use. If for example your first column had values such as "Smith, John" then your method of just splitting on commas will no longer work since you need to worry about how that field has escaped that comma. Using a CSV parser is a much more robust solution to the problem.

Comment: @Chris - I will definitely look into what others have suggested. Many thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

Creating an object model to hold the data is a good start

```
public class Donation {
    public string Donor { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Charity { get; set; }
}
```

Next you want to parse the data from the CSV file.

Something like [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) would help in parsing the data into usable objects.

```
var textReader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Donations.csv");
var csv = new CsvReader( textReader );
var records = csv.GetRecords<Donation>();
```

From there calculating the average using LINQ is a simple matter of calling the extension method on the parsed collection.

```
var average = records.Average(_ => _.Amount);
```

Comment: That certainly makes things look alot easier, I will definitely take a look at that, many thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If external Lib like [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) from [Nkosi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51785117/6560478) is not possible you can keep the same principle but parse it by hand like:

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Donor { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Charity { get; set; }
}


string csv =  File.ReadAllText(file);

//skip(1), for hearder
var lines = csv.Split(new char[] {'\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Skip(1);
List<Model> models = new List<Model>();

int id=1;
foreach (var item in lines)
{
    var values = item.Split(',');
    if(values.Count()!= 4) continue;//error loging

    var model = new Model
    {
        Id = id,
        Donor = values[0],
        Date = DateTime.Parse(values[1]),
        Amount = Decimal.Parse(values[2]),
        Charity = values[3]
    };

    models.Add(model);

    id++;
}
```

And now you can linq easly:

```
var result = models.Average(x=> x.Amount);
```

And for Average per person

```
var avgPerPerson = models 
                    .GroupBy(x=> x.Donor)
                    .Select(g=> new {
                      Donor = g.Key,
                      Average = g.Average(c => c.Amount)
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var total = 0.0d;
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(//FilePath))
{
    var lineArr = line.Split(',');

    double lineDonation;
    if (double.TryParse(lineArr[2])
        total += lineDonation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Microsoft Excel package "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel". you can easily download it from Nuget:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlsApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        if (xlsApp == null)
        {
            //Any message
        }

        Workbook wb = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\310231566\\Downloads\\main.xlsx",
            0, true, 5, "", "", true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true);
        Sheets sheets = wb.Worksheets;
        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);

        Range firstColumn = ws.UsedRange.Columns[1];
        System.Array myvalues = (System.Array)firstColumn.Cells.Value;
        string[] strArray = myvalues.OfType<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
        int j = 0;
        int avg = 0;
        int[] intArray = new int[strArray.Length-1];
        for (int i = 1; i < strArray.Length; i++)
        {
            intArray[j] = int.Parse(strArray[i]);
            avg  = avg + intArray[j];
            j++;
        }

        avg = avg/intArray.Length;
    }
```

Comment: This is certainly not something I have come across, will definitely take a look and try and understand it, many thanks

Comment: Sure, let me know if you need any help executing this code

Answer (score 0):

Average amount per donor onliner, with no failsafe :

```
var avg =  File
        .ReadAllLines(file)
        .Skip(1)
        .Select(x => x.Split(','))
        .Select((x,i) => new {
                Donor = values[0],
                Amount = Decimal.Parse(values[2])
            })
        .GroupBy(x=> x.Donor)
        .Select(g=> new {
          Donor = g.Key,
          AverageAmount = g.Average(c => c.Amount)
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I shall give this a go too!